# Where do I ask IT support questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about a problem I'm having installing optifine with forge on minecraft.  Is there a place where I could ask this question?  I asked this on gaming, but I just got downvoted and told it is the wrong place.  The question is here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220868/forge-not-launching-with-optifine

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions that boil down to "[software] is not working, what do I do?" are **technical support**, and the only reliable way to solve such problems is to contact the owner/creator of [software] about it. In many cases such a question is unanswerable on all SE sites simply because none of us wrote [software].

Arqade can *sometimes* help with these issues if they're so common and well-understood that many gamers have already been told the answer by a programmer or have discovered workarounds on their own. But in both of those cases it's probably an easily-googled factoid that inspires link-only answers, so it's unlikely to be well-received even if there is a known answer. Gamers themselves usually have no ability to debug [software] and thus can't help in the general case.

StackOverflow can't help with these because they aren't asking about a specific bug in a specific piece of code; nobody has any way of knowing what the exact technical issue is until someone with a fully functioning dev environment for [software] does some debugging and isolates the exact cause. This crosses the line from "sharing knowledge" to "working for free", so they won't respond well to such questions either.